# How to convert decimal values to time values in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

I have a table that is formatted like this:

```
date     | flag    |dec_time
04-MAY-21   2       0.54
04-MAY-21   5       2.18    
12-MAY-20   9       6.1
12-MAY-20   10      8
12-MAY-20   42      4
12-MAY-20   11      4.75
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
date     | flag    |new_dec_time
04-MAY-21   2       00:54
04-MAY-21   5       02:18   
12-MAY-20   9       06:10
12-MAY-20   10      08:00
12-MAY-20   42      04:00
12-MAY-20   11      04.75
```

Basically transform the values in the dec_time field into time values like the example above in new_dec_time.

This is my SQL so far:

```
select to_number(replace(dec_time,'.',':')) as new_dec_time
```

This simply changes replaces the decimal point with the semicolon but doesnt add the 0s where needed. Is there a simple way to go about doing this? Any ideas or suggestions would help.

Comment: Are you sure 0.54  is 00:54, i.e. 54 minutes; not 00:32:24, i.e. 32 and a bit minutes? Similarly 2.18 could mean 02:10:48, and 6.1 could mean 06:06:00. Depends whether the `dec` part implies they  are really base-10 multiples of 1 hour?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. It's because of the logic that I didn't inlcude in the code but 0.54 would be 00:54.......2.18 = 02:18.......6.1=06:10.........8=08:00,,etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never rely on default NLS settings if you need exact format. Always specify NLS parameters explicitly (for example, decimal separator in Russian is comma, not period).

So this is the query, if your numbers are restricted to valid time. If not, you'll get nonsense that looks like time. Also Oracle have no `time` datatype alone, that's why you need to implement operations with strings by yourself.

> ```
> with a as (
>   select 2.18 as h from dual union
>   select 0.54 from dual union
>   select 6.1 from dual
> )
> select
>   to_char(h, '00D00',
>   'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='': ''') as tm
> from a
> ```
>
> ```
> | TM     |
> | :----- |
> |  00:54 |
> |  02:18 |
> |  06:10 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7e8f5dc14ac8d28bbe779e61191df5da)*

Comment: If the leading space is an issue then you can suppress that with the FM format modifier - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=83133dad01b1b50e6b81edd13797d718).

Answer (score 0):

You want a *string* result, so don't use `to_number()`!

You want `lpad()`:

```
select lpad(replace(dec_time, '.', ':'), 5, '0')
```